# how to list unique urls from the given domain

Tags: python, list, url

I have written code to extract all urls from the given site, but the problem is some urls are repeated, and I want it a list with unique urls.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from termcolor import colored
import re, os

import requests

url = 'http://example.com'
ext = 'html'
count=0
countfiles=0
files=[]
def ulist(x):
  return list(dict.fromkeys(x))



def listFD(filename, ext=''):
  print filename
  print url
  if filename == url:
      page = requests.get(url).text
  else:
      page = requests.get(url + filename).text

  soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
  return ['/' + node.get('href') for node in soup.find_all('a') if node.get('href').endswith(ext)]



for file in ulist(listFD(url, ext)):
   for unfile in ulist(listFD(file, ext)):
    print unfile
```

Comment: i am expecting some working example

Comment: what do you mean? If you already have the list of urls, you just use the code provided in any of the answers...

Comment: for file in ulist(listFD(url, ext)):
   for unfile in ulist(listFD(file, ext)):
    print unfile                         here i am not storing in list directly printng so

Comment: what is `unfile`?

Comment: see in code  last  line , i want answer for my code .

Comment: the goal of this place is to help you figure out problems, not to solve your assignment or any coding problem you might encounter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can act below:

```
urls = list(set(urls))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap your list in python's builtin [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) functionality:

```
urls = ['www.google.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']
unique_urls = list(set(urls))
print(unique_urls)  # prints >> ['www.facebook.com', 'www.google.com']
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your list of urls, you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to get unique elements and a list comprehension:

```
unique_urls = [url for url in set(urls)]
```